# group by similar value of column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, mean, group

I'm using a DataFrame that contains sample data on rocks and soils. I want to create 2 separate plots, one for rocks and one for soils, showing SO3 composition relative to SIO2. I created a dictionary of rocks only, but there are still 90+ samples. As it's shown in the figure, some have similar names. For example 'Adirondack' appears 3 times. I could manually go through them all, but that would take a while (P.S. I did, but I would still like to know the easier way than `if ... elif ...` statements, since I had to manually create a legend entry to avoid many duplicate entries).

How can I just group together the ones with the same x letters and save them in a new dataframe or my dictionary as just 'Adirondack (all)', for example (take the part of the name before the '_' perhaps, so that it will appear in the legend that way), and have the three sets of values for 'Adirondack_' etc. in one dictionary entry.

[image]

```
Rocks = APXSData[APXSData.Type.str.contains('R')]
RockLabels = Rocks['Sample'].to_list()
RockDict = {}

for i in RockLabels:
    SiO2val = np.extract(Rocks["Sample"]==i, Rocks["SiO2"])
    SO3val = np.extract(Rocks["Sample"]==i, Rocks["SO3"])
    newKey = i  
    RockDict[newKey] = {'SiO2':SiO2val, 'SO3':SO3val}

DatabyRockSample = pd.DataFrame(RockDict)

fig = plt.figure() 

for i in RockLabels:
    plt.scatter(
        DatabyRockSample[i]["SiO2"],
        DatabyRockSample[i]["SO3"], 
        marker='o', 
        label = i)    #, color = colors[count], edgecolors = edgecolor[count], 

plt.xlabel("SiO$_2$", labelpad = 10)
plt.ylabel("SO$_3$", labelpad = 10)
plt.title('Composition of all rocks \n at Gusev Crater')
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's prepare some dummy data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sol': [14,18,33,34,41],
    'Type': ['SU','RU','RB','RR','SU'],
    'Sample': ['Gusev_Soil','Adirondack_asis','Adirondack_brush','Adirondack_RAT','Gusev_Other'],
    'N': [45,126,129,128,76],
    'Na2O': [2.8,2.3,2.8,2.4,2.7],
    # ...
})
```

So here's our data frame:

```
   Sol Type            Sample    N  Na2O
0   14   SU        Gusev_Soil   45   2.8
1   18   RU   Adirondack_asis  126   2.3
2   33   RB  Adirondack_brush  129   2.8
3   34   RR    Adirondack_RAT  128   2.4
4   41   SU       Gusev_Other   76   2.7
```

We can use grouping in this way.

If the only option we have is matching first n letters, then:

```
n = 5   
grouper = df['Sample'].str[:n]
groups = {name: group for name, group in df.groupby(grouper)}
```

If we can extract meaningful data by splitting, which is better I think, then:

```
# in this case we can split by '_' and get the first word
grouper = df['Sample'].str.split('_').str.get(0)   
groups = {name: group for name, group in df.groupby(grouper)}
```

If splitting isn't that simple, say our words are separated by space, underscore or hyphen, then we could use `str.extract` method:

```
grouper = df['Sample'].str.extract('\A(.*)(?=[ _-])')
groups = {name: group for name, group in df.groupby(grouper)}
```

We can also avoid creating dictionaries. Let's see how we can iterate over the groups obtained by splitting as an example:

```
grouper = df['Sample'].str.split('_').str.get(0)
groups = df.groupby(grouper)
for name, dataframe in groups:
    print(f'name: {name}')
    print(dataframe, '\n')
```

Output:

```
name: Adirondack
   Sol Type            Sample    N  Na2O
1   18   RU   Adirondack_asis  126   2.3
2   33   RB  Adirondack_brush  129   2.8
3   34   RR    Adirondack_RAT  128   2.4 

name: Gusev
   Sol Type       Sample   N  Na2O
0   14   SU   Gusev_Soil  45   2.8
4   41   SU  Gusev_Other  76   2.7
```

The same with rocks. IMO we can do better than `APXSData.Type.str.contains('R')`:

```
APXSData['Type'].str[0] == 'R'
APXSData['Type'].str.startswith('R')
```

Let's separate rocks and group them by the leading name:

```
is_rock = df['Type'].str.startswith('R')
grouper = df['Sample'].str.split('_').str.get(0)
groups_of_rocks = df[is_rock].groupby(grouper)

for k,v in groups_of_rocks:
    print(k)
    print(v)
```

Output:

```
Adirondack
   Sol Type            Sample    N  Na2O
1   18   RU   Adirondack_asis  126   2.3
2   33   RB  Adirondack_brush  129   2.8
3   34   RR    Adirondack_RAT  128   2.4
```

To plot data for some group of interest only, we can use `get_group(name)`:

```
groups.get_group('Adirondack').plot.bar(x='Sample', y=['N','Na2O'])
```

See also:

- [detail about str in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)
- [pandas.Series.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)
- [pandas.Series.str.get](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html)
- [pandas.Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)
- [regex in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
- run `help('pandas.core.strings.StringMethods')` to see help offline

Comment: Thanks! That's a very comprehensive solution. Unfortunately, some of the site names are 'Fools_Gold', 'Temples_dwarf', 'Pot_of_Gold' etc. though not that many. That's my fault for not giving more of the source data. That's still very useful, though, for comparing the abundances using the different measurement techniques.